# How to access the OTHER half of texture? (after applying mirror modifier to a textured half)

Tags: texturing, mirror

I am new to Blender, and have created and textured (painted) a symmetrical model using the mirror modifier (this character is 99% symmetrical in shape and colour).

Now I want to do some further work on it as a NON-symmetrical object, with textures and geometrical changes on one side only. But I have no idea how to do this.

Is there a way to generate a new completed texture from this image? Preferably retaining the relative position of the UV mesh on the texture I made? I'd prefer to avoid creating a non-symmetrical texture from scratch, as this object requires a highly detailed texture that needs to be 99% symmetrical. It also needs to be low-poly.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the mirror modifier. If you dont apply it before unwrapping, both sites will be overlapped (usefull if you want symetrical textures).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying. My problem is that after applying the mirror modifier, and then unwrap, I get the new mesh superimposed over the original (half-side) texture map. I was hoping for a way to duplicate the missing half of the texture itself, and if possible, with the full-model UV mesh connected.

Comment: So, do you apply and THEN unwrap? 
It is possible (but not likely) that the islands are still at the same position. Try hovering over the island and press "L" and then "G" to move it. What happens? Also, did you mark the "middle" (the mirror point, the part where the modifier half and the real half come together) as a uv seam?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I get a totally new set of islands, but the half texture I painted doesn't change. I was hoping there was a way to duplicate that as well. As it is, I now have a complete mesh of my polygons, but don't know how to reach the other half of the texture.

Comment: So, you dont know which part of you uv islands corresponds to which part of your mesh? Or did i get you wrong?

Comment: Yeah, my problem is a little different. I know my way around the UV island meshes fine. What happened is I created and completed a fully textured 'half' model using the mirror modifier; and now I want to add some new asymmetrical details to it, but don't know how to do this (my texture file is still a half-texture that still has some kind of mirror modifier attached, and I want to add details on one side but not the other.

Comment: Oh, now i get it.

You could move the texture island arround, open gimp/photoshop/etc. copy and paste the textured part of your texture and place the island on it.

Comment: That works nicely! Cheers

Comment: Nice to hear :)